# Is this a worker, or something else?

Tags: species-identification, sexual-dimorphism, bees

As far as I understand, this is a buff-tailed bumble bee (*Bombus terrestris*). It was collected (dying) inside my house in Santiago, Chile. The species was intentionally introduced not far away, for agriculture, some years ago.

Looking for descriptions, I see it is huge for its species, queens reportedly being 20-22 mm ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombus_terrestris#Description_and_identification), [2](https://wildflower-favours.co.uk/know-your-bees/)). I also learned that workers span a wide range of sizes, depending on age (but not this large, supposedly.)

Now, for the caste/sex, I'm stuck due to lack of experience. [This site](https://www.bumblebeeconservation.org/identification-tips/) suggests looking at pollen baskets in the hind legs for females (I think I see one, but can't be sure since I don't know exactly what to look at, despite browsing some example photos), but then hairy hind legs (again, I think I might see them, but I'm much less confident) and facial hair for males (I don't really have a point of comparison, but it has some short, black hair in the frons: see expanded photo). Common descriptions also suggests buff color for the tails for queens, but I have seen [white-tailed queens](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/96806531) around too.

I'd really like to acquire the experience needed.

**Is this an old worker, or something else?**

[image: maybe 23 mm long?]

[image]

Comment: this is very likely a queen as they are 20-23mm long but to give a definitive answer you need to measure the lenght of the wings,if they are 38-43 mm it is a queen.the body of a male is 14-16mm the lenght of the wings are 30-33mm and the workers are 11-17mm long and the wings are 22-34 mm long.this is not an answer only some easy to find information.

Comment: @trondhansen, thank you! I also read that queens are supposed to have a shorter tongue, which doesn't seem to be the case. I was wondering if there could have been a selective pressure towards larger individuals, vaguely analogous to leg length in [cane toads in Australia](https://www.nature.com/news/2006/060213/full/news060213-4.html)

Comment: I mean, introduction is still relatively recent. Wingspan is about 45 mm BTW (about twice the body length, like all three queens, workers and males)